# When is a subspace of a Hilbert space large?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, definition

In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372081), Halmos defines what it means for a subspace of a Hilbert space to be ***large***.

> **Definition.** A subspace $H$ of a Hilbert space $K$ is *large* if $H$ contains infinitely many orthogonal copies of its orthogonal complement, or, in other words, if $\dim H \ge \aleph_0 \dim (K\setminus H)$. Thus, for example, a subspace of a separable Hilbert space is *large* if and only if it is infinite-dimensional.

1. What does the author mean by *"infinitely many orthogonal copies of its orthogonal complement"*? Does it refer to infinitely many subspaces inside $H$, which are all orthogonal, and also isomorphic to $H^\perp$? A concrete example would help me appreciate this more!
2. If $H$ is not closed, $K\setminus H$ may not be a vector space, so how can we talk about its dimension?
3. How would you prove that a subspace of a separable Hilbert space is *large* if and only if it is infinite-dimensional?

This is the first time I have seen this definition, so it would be great if you could point me to any other related references. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "Copy of X" here means "space that is isomorphic to X".  So the condition is indeed that $H$ should contain infinitely many subspaces, each of which is isomorphic to the orthogonal complement $H^\perp$, and which are pairwise orthogonal to each other.

   A concrete example might be $K = L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $H = L^2(0,\infty)$.  Then $H^\perp = L^2(-\infty,0)$.  Let $H_i = L^2(i, i+1)$, which you can show is isomorphic to $L^2(-\infty, 0)$, and the $H_i$ are all pairwise orthogonal.  So $H$ is an example of a large subspace.
2. The notation $K \setminus H$ here doesn't mean set difference, but orthogonal complement.  So $K \setminus H$ is just the orthogonal complement of $H$ in $K$, which you could also denote $H^\perp$ when the ambient space $K$ is understood.  It is certainly a closed subspace of $K$, and it makes sense to speak of its dimension.

   The $K \setminus H$ notation is fairly common, and although it is technically ambiguous with set difference, in practice it is usually clear from context which one is meant.
3. Let $H$ be a subspace of the separable Hilbert space $K$.  It is clear that a large subspace must be infinite-dimensional (it contains infinitely many nontrivial orthogonal subspaces).

   For the converse, suppose $H$ is infinite-dimensional, and fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2, \dots\}$ for $H$.  Let $H^\perp$ be its orthogonal complement.

   Suppose first that $H^\perp$ has finite dimension $n$.  For each $i > 0$ let $H_i$ be the subspace of $H$ spanned by $\{e_{ni+1}, \dots, e_{ni+n}\}$.    Each $H_i$ is isomorphic to $H^\perp$ because they have the same dimension $n$, and the $H_i$ are pairwise orthogonal because they are spanned by disjoint subsets of an orthogonal set.  Thus $H$ is large.

   Otherwise, suppose $H^\perp$ is infinite-dimensional; since it is separable, it has a countable orthonormal basis $\{f_1, f_2, \dots\}$.  Let  $\{ k_{1,1}, k_{1,2}, \dots\}$, $\{k_{2,1}, k_{2,2}, \dots\}$ be infinitely many disjoint sequences in $\mathbb{N}$; for instance you could enumerate the primes as $p_n$ and let $k_{n,i} = p_n^i$.  Let $H_i$ be the closed linear span of $\{e_{k_{i,1}}, e_{k_{i,2}}, \dots\}$.  Each $H_i$ is isomorphic to $H^\perp$, because $H^\perp, H_i$ are both infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces, or because they both have orthonormal bases of the same cardinality $\aleph_0$.  And the $H_i$ are again pairwise orthogonal because they are the closed linear spans of disjoint orthogonal sets.  Thus $H$ is also large in this case.

   In essence, it's really just the fact that a countably infinite set can be written as a countable union of countable sets (or of finite sets), i.e. that $\aleph_0 = \aleph_0^2$, applied to dimension instead of cardinality.

The term "large subspace" seems to have been introduced by Halmos and I haven't seen it used by anyone else; the concept is not one that I think comes up especially often.  I wouldn't particularly expect there to be a lot of reference material on the topic.  It does appear in Halmos's *Hilbert Space Problem Book* on [page 131](https://books.google.com/books?id=MK_aBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA131&ots=7LMQ3pXQ-L&dq=hilbert%20%22large%20subspace%22&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q=hilbert%20%22large%20subspace%22&f=false), where he says that "the idea has appeared before, even if the term has not".