# Every Hermitian operator with a large kernel is the direct sum of positive and negative operators with large kernels

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In [*Commutators of Operators*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372081) by Paul R. Halmos, the following result is used to conclude the proof of Lemma $2$. Please help me with a proof of the same.

> "It suffices to note that every Hermitian operator is the direct sum of a positive and a negative operator, and, in case the original operator has a large null space, then the direct summands can be selected so that they too have that property."

In this context, *"large"* means (as discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369713/when-is-a-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space-large) also):

> A subspace $H$ of a Hilbert space is *large* if $H$ contains infinitely many orthogonal copies of its orthogonal complement, or, in other words, if $\dim H \ge \aleph_0 \dim (H^\perp)$.

---

**My attempt:**

> **Spectral Theorem**. If $A$ is a normal operator on a Hilbert space, then there exists a measure space $(X,\mu)$ and $h\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ such that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to the operator $M_h$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

As a corollary, we have $\sigma(A) = \sigma(M_h) = \operatorname{essran} h$ and $A = A^*$ if and only if $\sigma(A) \subset \Bbb R$.

As $A^* = A$, by the spectral theorem there exists unitary $U$ such that $U^*AU = M_h$ where $M_h:L^2(X,\mu) \to L^2(X,\mu)$ and $h\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$. Define $Y:= \{x\in X: h(x)\ge 0\}$ and $Z:=\{x\in X: h(x) < 0\}$. Since $\mu(X\setminus (Y\cup Z)) = 0$ (as $\operatorname{essran} h \subset \Bbb R$), we have $h = \mathbf{1}_Yh + \mathbf{1}_Z h$ a.e. on $X$. Therefore, $M_h = M_{\mathbf{1}_Y h} + M_{\mathbf{1}_Z h}$. $M_{\mathbf{1}_Y h}$ is a positive operator, so $UM_{\mathbf{1}_Y h} Y^*$ is also a positive operator. $M_{\mathbf{1}_Z h}$ is a negative operator, so $UM_{\mathbf{1}_Z h} U^*$ is also a negative operator. Furthermore, their product is zero, since $M_{\mathbf{1}_Y h} M_{\mathbf{1}_Z h} = \mathbf{0}$. Indeed, we have found a direct sum decomposition of $A$ in terms of a positive and a negative operator.
It remains to show that $$\ker (UM_hU^*) \subset \ker (UM_{\mathbf{1_Y} h} U^*)$$ and $$\ker (UM_hU^*) \subset \ker (UM_{\mathbf{1_Z} h} U^*)$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use functional calculus.

Given $f(t)=\max\{t,0\}$ and $g(t)=\min\{t,0\}$, then both are continuous and $f(t)+g(t)=t$. So you can define
$$
P=f(A),\qquad N=-g(A). 
$$
Since $f(t)g(t)=0$ for all $t$, $PN=0$. Since both are selfadjoint, this is enough to guarantee that $P-N$ is an orthogonal direct sum.

Finally, because $f(0)=g(0)=0$,
$$
\ker P\supset\ker A,\qquad \ker N\supset\ker A. 
$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very familiar with functional calculus, so what are some very basic things I'd need to know to understand your proof? Also, do you have any ideas for a proof that avoids functional calculus? I imagine it would be more complicated though.

Comment: Well, that's pretty basic. What do you know about operators? Do you know the spectral theorem?

Comment: I know the spectral theorem for compact normal operators, but not more generally. If you could point me to some place where I could learn these basics of functional calculus, that might be good too!

Comment: The inclusion of the kernels should be reversed.

Comment: @MaoWao: indeed! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @connected-subgroup: Most books on Functional Analysis should have it. Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis* is the first one that comes to mind.  For a general selfadjoint operator, the sum you have in the compact version of the Spectral Theorem becomes an integral: $$ A=\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda),$$ where $E$ is a *spectral measure* on $\sigma(A)$. By integrating $f(\lambda)$ instead you get $f(A)$. Alternatively, you have  a unitary  $H\to L^2(X)$ for a certain $X$ and $UAU^*$ is a multiplication operator $M_g$ with $g\in L^\infty$. Then you can do $f(M_g)=M_{f\circ g}$

Comment: @MartinArgerami I have finally learned the spectral theorem for normal operators. Now, I understand that if $A=A^*$ there exists a unitary $U$ such that $UAU^* = M_h$, where $h\in L^\infty$ and $M_h: L^2 \to L^2$ is a multiplication operator. Could you suggest a proof using this?

Comment: The proof I wrote uses it. Is anything not clear?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I have updated my post to include an attempt using the spectral theorem. Could you please help me out with the last part (concerning **kernels**)? I have found a direct sum decomposition. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the decomposition you found is the same one as in my answer. The kernel inclusion is trivial : $$ \ker (UM_gU^*)=\ker (M_gU^*)=U\ker M_g.$$ So all you need to show is that $\ker M_{h}\subset \ker M_{gh}$, ,which is obvious because $M_{gh}=M_gM_h$.