# Lemma $2$ in Commutators of Operators by Paul R. Halmos

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I need help understanding the proof of Lemma $2$ in the paper [*Commutators of Operators*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372081) by Paul R. Halmos. The proof depends on Lemma $1$ of the same paper, which I have quoted at the end of this post. Throughout, all Hilbert spaces are complex, and if $\mathcal H$ is a complex Hilbert space, $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ denotes the collection of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal H$, and $[A, B] = AB-BA$ is the commutator of $A, B\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$.

---

> **Lemma $2$.** A Hermitian operator with a large nullspace is a self-commutator.

A subspace $H$ of a Hilbert space is *large* if $H$ contains infinitely many orthogonal copies of its orthogonal complement, or, in other words, if $\dim H \ge \aleph_0 \dim (H^\perp)$.

> *Proof.* Suppose first that the given Hermitian operator is positive, i. e. that it can be written in the form $A^2$ with a Hermitian $A$.

Note that $\ker A = \ker A^2$. This is easy to prove and will be useful later.

> Let $H$ be the closure of the range of $A$. Since $H$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$, there is no loss of generality in assuming that the originally given Hilbert space $\widetilde H$ contains the direct sum $K$ of countably many copies of $H$, and that, moreover, $H$ is embedded in $K$ so that it coincides with the set of all those sequences $x$ in $K$ for which $x_n = 0$ whenever $n > 1$.

**Question**. Could someone please explain the above extract in detail? As $H = \overline{\operatorname{ran} A}$, $H$ is a subspace of $\widetilde H$. $K$ is the direct sum of countably many copies of $H$, i.e. it consists of sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset H$. Certainly, it *does not make sense* for $K$ to be a subspace of $\widetilde H$, since the elements of $K$ are sequences (of elements from $H\subset \widetilde H$). So, how can we assume that $\widetilde H$ contains $K$? Perhaps the author has conveniently swept the mention of certain isomorphisms under the rug. On another note, the embedding $H \hookrightarrow K$ is clear to me.

> If an operator $P$ is defined on $K$, as in Lemma $1$, and extended to $\widetilde H$ by defining it to be $0$ (or, for that matter, any normal operator) on the orthogonal complement $\widetilde H - K$, then Lemma $1$ implies the desired result. If the given operator is negative, the representation can be achieved with $P^*$ in place of $P$. The case of a general Hermitian operator can be treated by putting together the results of the positive and the negative cases. It suffices to note that every Hermitian operator is the direct sum of a positive and a negative operator, and, in case the original operator has a large null space, then the direct summands can be selected so that they too have that property.

---

*Lemma $1$*:

> Let $K$ be the direct sum of countably many copies of $H$. Suppose $A\in \mathcal B(H)$ is Hermitian, and define $B\in \mathcal B(K)$ by $(Bx)_n := Ax_n$. Define another operator $U \in \mathcal B(K)$ by $(Ux)_1 := 0$ and $(Ux)_n := x_{n-1}$ for all $n > 1$.
> **Lemma $1$.** If $P = BU$, then $([P]x)_1 = A^2x_1$ and $([P]x)_n = 0$ for $n > 1$, where $[P] = [P^*,P] = P^*P - PP^*$.

---

*Related Posts*:

1. [Every Hermitian operator with a large kernel is the direct sum of positive and negative operators with large kernels.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374670/every-hermitian-operator-with-a-large-kernel-is-the-direct-sum-of-positive-and-n)
2. [When is a subspace of a Hilbert space large?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369713/when-is-a-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space-large)

Comment: While I don't personally mind, the edit police will not be happy if you edit your question to ask for more stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioning every isomorphism would make most math unreadable. Since $\ker A$ is large and $\operatorname{ran} A\subset \ker A^\perp\subset\mathcal H$, by hypothesis countably many pairwise orthogonal copies exist in $\mathcal H$. You can arrange these subspaces so that they are named $H_1=\overline{\operatorname{ran} }A,H_2,H_3,\ldots$, with $H_k\simeq H_j$ and $H_k\perp H_j$ for all $k\ne j$.

So
$$
K=\Big\{\sum_k h_k:\ h_k\in H_k,\ k\in\mathbb N\Big\} 
$$
is canonically isomorphic to the space of sequences mentioned in the question. This has to do with the fact that there are two concepts of "direct sum". Both are the same in a sense, but they are different.

The *external* direct sum of a family $\{H_j\}$ of Hilbert space is
$$
\bigoplus_{j\in J}H_j=\Big\{f:J\to\bigcup_{j\in J}H_j,\ f(j)\in H_j\text{ for all }j,\ \sum_j\|f(j)\|^2<\infty\Big\}.
$$
Note that there is no requirement for the $H_j$ to be related in any sense, they could have different dimension, and we can do things like $\mathbb C^2\oplus \ell^2(\mathbb N)\oplus L^2[0,1]$.

The *internal* direct sum of a family $\{H_j\}$ of pairwise orthogonal subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$ is
$$
\bigoplus_{j\in J}H_j=\Big\{\sum_j h_j:\ h_j\in H_j\text{ for all } j,\ \sum_j\|h_j\|^2<\infty\Big\}. 
$$
The notation for both is the same because, when the internal sum makes sense, both are canonically isomorphic, i.e. you can identify the element $\sum_jh_j$ with $\{h_j\}$ in a linear, bijective, isometric way.

Comment: 1. $\ker A$ is large means that $\ker A$ (and not $\ker A^\perp$) contains infinitely many orthogonal copies of $\ker A^\perp$, hence also those of $\operatorname{ran} A$ (and $\overline{\operatorname{ran} A}$). 2. Why just *countably many* copies? Could be more, right? 3. You say that $H_1 = \overline{\operatorname{ran} A}$; but on the previous line there is no mention of the *closure*. Perhaps you meant closure in both places?

Comment: Yes, the perp should have not been there and the point is that they are in $\mathcal H$. 2. Because you said so in the definition of *large*. 3. Yes, it's not important because $\ker A$ is closed, so if it contains a subspace it contains its closure.

Comment: About 2: The definition says $\dim H \ge \aleph_0 \dim (H^\perp)$, so $\dim H  = 2^{\aleph_0} \dim (H^\perp)$ etc. are in fact valid possibilities. We don't have to assume countability. /// 4. While all of this is fine, my question still remains. You write $$K=\Big\{\sum_k h_k:\ h_k\in H_k,\ k\in\mathbb N\Big\}$$ but Halmos defines the *direct sum* as $$K=\Big\{(h_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}:\ h_k\in H_k,\ k\in\mathbb N, \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \|h_k\|^2 < \infty\Big\}$$
I'm confused due to the difference. The latter definition of $K$ asserts that it consists of sequences, which is unexpected.

Comment: The fact that the dimension *could* be bigger does not guarantee that it is. You are only guaranteed countably many copies, which is enough for the proof.  As for 4., the difference is the idea of *external* direct sum versus *internal*. The external is abstract, as there is no expected relation between the objects. So you define $\bigoplus_J H_j=\{f:J\to\bigoplus H_j:\ f(j)\in H_j, \sum\|f(j)\|^2<\infty\}$, which are your sequences. But inside a Hilbert space you can construct a proper sum of pairwise orthogonal subspaces; this will be canonically isomorphic to the external direct sum.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up *A LOT*. You could consider adding the part about external and internal direct sums to your answer since that was *really what caused me the confusion*.  In any case, just to confirm, the two are canonically isomorphic in this case since $$\infty > \left\|\sum_{k\in \Bbb N} h_k \right\|^2 = \langle \sum_{k\in \Bbb N} h_k, \sum_{k\in \Bbb N} h_k \rangle  = \sum_{k\in \Bbb N} \langle h_k, h_k\rangle = \sum_{k\in \Bbb N} \|h_k\|^2$$
right? We use the continuity of the inner product in both coordinates, and pairwise orthogonality of $\{H_k\}_{k\in \Bbb N}$.

Comment: Good. Yes, I'll edit that a bit later.